# How to correct this error in my haskell code:

Tags: haskell

i Have a code:

```
module Task5 where

import Prelude

data Stream a = a :& Stream a

infixl 4 :&

add :: Num a => a -> a -> a
add a b = a + b

instance  Num a => Num (Stream a ) where
    (+) (ia:&a) (ib :& b) = (ia + ib) :& ((+) a b)

    (-) (ia :& a) (ib :& b) = ((-) ia ib) :& (-) a b
    (*) (ia :& a) (ib :& b) = ((*) ia ib) :& (*) a b
    negate (i1 :& a) = negate i1 :& negate a
    abs (i1 :& a) = abs i1 :& abs a
    signum (i1 :& a) = signum i1 :& signum a
    fromInteger (i1 :& a) = fromInteger i1 :& fromInteger a
```

and have a 2 error:

```
Task5.hs:20:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `Integer'
                with actual type `Stream Integer'
    In the pattern: i1 :& a
    In an equation for `fromInteger':
        fromInteger (i1 :& a) = fromInteger i1 :& fromInteger a
    In the instance declaration for `Num (Stream a)'

Task5.hs:20:59:
    Couldn't match expected type `Integer'
                with actual type `Stream Integer'
    In the first argument of `fromInteger', namely `a'
    In the second argument of `(:&)', namely `fromInteger a'
    In the expression: fromInteger i1 :& fromInteger a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I dont understand how to correct this problem, so How correct this problem?)) And what you can advise me to read for learning haskell?

Comment: fromInteger has type Integer -> a so the argument to it should be an integer, not a stream. It's for converting an integer to your num instance.

Comment: *"And what you can advise me to read for learning haskell?"* [RWH](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/), [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters), the [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell), but most important: __read the signatures of the functions you're using when you encounter errors__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `fromInteger` is

```
Num a => Integer -> a
```

so it is for converting an `Integer` into your `Num` type. The first argument to `fromInteger` should therefore be an `Integer`, however in your implementation:

```
fromInteger (i1 :& a) = fromInteger i1 :& fromInteger a
```

it is a `Stream`.

One possible implementation would be to create an infinite stream of converted integer values e.g.

```
fromInteger i = (fromInteger i) :& (fromInteger i)
```

Comment: @gyok What do you want your `fromInteger` method to do? It seems like you want it to take a stream and perform the `fromInteger` operation of the underlying num type on each of its elements. As Lee said, you can't do that because `fromInteger` takes an Integer. So you "fix" it, by making `fromInteger` do something else - something that actually operates on an Integer.

Comment: Yes , anderstand, but i want if stream have integer elements like (5 &: 6 &: 7...) frominteger works with it

Comment: @gyok The question is: when the user writes something like `42 :: Stream Int`, what do you want to happen? That's when `fromInteger` would be called (with the Integer `42` as the argument). Something like `fromInteger (5 &: 6 &: 7...)` wouldn't be legal because the argument to `fromInteger` is always an Integer.

Comment: @gyok - I've added a possible implementation.

Comment: Can I suggest manually tying the knot with `fromInteger i = keepGoing where` `singleValue = fromInteger i` `keepGoing = singleValue :& keepGoing`, to avoid potential re-evaluation of `(fromInteger i)`. (The brackets aren't necessary in the last line.)